# Raising events/subscribing to them through an instance of the class

Tags: c#, object, events, delegates, subscribe

Below is a program which simply prints 'Success' on the screen using an event.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public event EventHandler TestEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new();
        program.Start();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        TestEvent += Print;
        TestEvent(null, null);
    }

    public void Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }

}
```

This works as intended. However, if I try to access the TestEvent event through an instance of the class, it throws an exception, saying that TestEvent was null, as if program.TestEvent and TestEvent are referring to two completely different things.

```
void Start()
{
    Program program = new();
    program.TestEvent += Print;
    program.TestEvent(null, null);
}
```

Modifying either of the two lines this way causes the same exception to be thrown.

Now, this is not a big issue per se, since there's no real *need* to access the event through an instance of the class (unless the event is a member of another class, in which case the approach works just fine). I'm just wondering what rule I'm breaking, since to me both chunks of code seem like they should do the same thing. Clearly that's not the case.

Comment: Shouldn't this `Program program = new();` instead be `Program program = new Program();`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi both approaches work with C#9 if the type is apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem here.

Have your tried this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program program = new Program();
    program.TestEvent += program.Print;
    program.TestEvent(null, null);
    program.Start();
}
```

Btw, you should always use follwing pattern to raise events: TestEvent?.Invoke(null,null)

Answer (score 0):

In Main(), as the entry point, it has already initialized an instance of Program class.

> ```
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     Program program = new();
>     program.Start();
> }
> ```

It is not necessary to create another one. You cannot invoke the other instance from within current Program. Actually it is even not necessary to initialized a instance of Program since Main method is static. It also works like this：

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
   Start();
}

void Start()
{
    TestEvent += Print;
    TestEvent(null, null);
}
```

May [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) on microsoft Docs helps you.